# (Lazy) Haskell undefined/bottom in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, undefined, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

Haskell has a really swell `undefined` value, which lazily raises an exception (upon evaluation). Ocaml is of course strict, so [as far as I can tell there is no equivalent of Haskell's `undefined`](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Undefined_values#OCaml). This is unfortunate though, because it means there is no bottom type for values. Let's say I wanted an

```
val a : int
```

I could of course do

```
let a = failwith "undefined"
let () =
  print_string "something unrelated\n"
```

And this happily compiles. Unfortunately, upon running it we get the undefined exception (which is expected).

What I want is to let `a` be a bottom/`undefined` value without changing its type (so things like `Lazy` won't work). Is this possible?

**extra details:**
So what I'm asking for probably sounds fairly silly. To curtail any commentary on why I shouldn't be doing this, allow me to briefly describe my use case. I'm writing a script that modifies the AST of an `mli` file to produce a "empty" `ml` file which matches its signatures. For the general case, it's possible to have `val a : int` in your `mli` so I need a way to generically synthesize a bottom type. `failwith "undefined"` works if all I needed was for compilation to succeed. But unfortunately, I also need to link this `ml` file against an OUnit test suite and run it (obviously the suite will fail, but the purpose is to be able to run it with `-list-test` so I can programmatically get a list of all tests).

**more details:**
I recognize that the proper way to solve this (probably) is to write a function which can generate the bottom type for any generic type. For the builtin primitives (and `list`, `option`, etc.) this is simple enough (just verbose). This becomes more complicated with records (perhaps defined in the stdlib, but also may be defined in the same file or a different package). To handle this my AST transformer then needs to have a complete understanding of the OCaml type system and file importing strategies for packages, which is a lot more logic than I want to/should include in it.

Comment: To be honest, I think it will be easier to do what you want by hand than to generate those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important note:** As noted by @PatJ and @camlspotter, `Obj.magic` can lead to some horrendous behavior. In fact, I'd venture using something that it returns without some sort of proof (such as with Coq) that its use was warranted is akin to undefined behavior in C. You could get nothing, you could get a segfault, or you could set your house on fire. All are possible. The solution below should **only** be used if you **never use or call any undefined values.** So, it is fine for my case, because I need to only link an OUnit test suite against this package with undefined values (but OUint **never calls anything in the package**). This allows you to run the OUint test suite with `-list-test` (with `failwith` running the test binary fails immeidately in the case of `let a = failwith "undefined"`). But since `-list-test` never runs any of the code its linked against, it never tries to use the undefined values, so this particular use case is safe. Proceed with caution.

I managed to find a rather hacky solution. The `Obj` module enables some fancy runtime things that requires some loose types (and doesn't appear to do runtime checking). It offers some functions with some promising signatures:

```
type t 
val repr : 'a -> t
val obj : t -> 'a
val magic : 'a -> 'b
```

After some experimentation, it's clear these are unsafe operations (they don't do any runtime checks), which is perfect for our use case (since we don't really care too much what happens if you try to use these stubbed out values). Either of these appear to be sufficient equivalents to Haskell's `undefined`:

```
Obj.obj (Obj.repr 0) (* 0 could be unit, another primitive, etc. *)
Obj.magic 0
```

Now of course the equivalency ends when you try to use these values anywhere. You may hit some segfaults. For my aforementioned use case this is fine because OUnit `-list-test` never actually runs the tests (and if it did they are run in separate processes, so the segfaults don't affect the test harness).

I'd be curious to hear if anyone with more experience with OCaml internals can comment on this approach. It would be really cool (although not really required in this context) if using the values resulted in an exception instead of a potential segfault (or some other undefined behavior--which for `0` sometimes appears to be nothing happening).

Comment: As far as I know, Obj might be required in some cases. For instance, when Coq generates ocaml, he sometimes uses it [1], in particular section 23.3.

[1] https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/extraction.html

Comment: @Bromind That's a good source you've cited. Interesting read. Gives me a bit more confidence that my use of  `Obj.magic` here isn't totally unwarranted (because it's somewhat like the first bullet point). Thanks!

Comment: This is a bad idea and it may well turn out very bad for you. Coq uses Obj in selected cases when it generates OCaml. But Coq is developed by hardened OCaml hackers who communicate with the OCaml dev team. Also, the code they generate is formally proven, which is not your case. The minute there is a problem in your code, a segmentation fault would be the **best** case scenario. Running tests on magic'd values is like putting a leash on Godzilla: it will work until Godzilla moves.

Comment: I don't actually think this is as bad, because this code is never called. I see how this has a parallel to undefined behavior in C. But, at least in my case, none of this code is ever run. As I mentioned, I only need something that typechecks and doesn't immediately die on run due to a `let a = failwith "undefined"`. OUint will never run any of the code I linked, so any undefined behavior will never happen. But I'll add a note to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

OCaml has no `undefined`.  I think it is fortunate since the only trouble I have in Haskell is the laziness. :-P

I avoid `Obj.magic` at all costs.  Test code with `Obj.magic` does not sound proper tests...

To avoid immediate failure of the value of `int`, I would change the type to `unit -> int` or `int option` to have easy default values.

```
let a = fun () -> failwith "undefined"
let a = None
```

Or, maybe, generating default values of given types generically using `[@@deriving xxx]` may work well for your case, since you have mli.  But I am afraid that it requires a new deriver for `ppx_deriving` or programming with `typerep` and `ppx_typerep_conv`.

Comment: As mentioned in my question (edits at the bottom), unfortunately I can't change the types. I'm working with given implementations that I don't control. Also, no test code will have `Obj.magic`. The test code expects to be linked against something with a known interface (the one I don't control). I need to be able to run the OUnit tests with `-list-test`, but I can't do this without compiling against an implementation of that interface. I'm dynamically creating a dummy implementation (using `Obj.magic` to massage the types where necessary) and linking against that only to get the list of tests.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anyone mentioning `assert false`, which might not be bottom (`⊥`), because it has a value, but is general `type a. a`.

I see it in "runtime shouldn't reach here, but type checker does" match expressions.
It allows a subset of Haskell's `undefined` usages because OCaml is not pervasively lazy, and will blow-up if you say something like:

```ml
let undefined = assert false
let _ = List.length [undefined; undefined; undefined]
```

Also according to the OCaml manual, `assert false` is a special case of assertions and `-noassert` has no effect on it because it gets directly reduced to the assertion exception.. Giving it its polymorphic property.

Aside, it fails where the assertion is, so when you do something like

```ml
(*1*) let undefined = assert false
(*n*) let... = undefined
```

the assertion, if it happens for some reason, will point at the wrong lines of code, namely line no. 1 as opposed to line n.

Additionally, there's the `(??)` which I believe is reserved for camlp4 in the manual but merlin recognizes it. It may be closer in usage to Haskell's `undefined`; has no value and is used as a type-checked placeholder. Unlike `assert false`, it won't even compile.